# mongod and mongo commands not working on windows 10

Tags: mongodb

I've installed mongoDB on my windows 10 OS. Then I tried setting its database path to some directory by moving to it and typing `mongod --datapath=data` in cmd, where data is the folder which is to contain the db(I've used the relative path because I'm in that directory). But message comes that mongod is unrecognized command. After some searching I found that by specifying mongod path, i.e. `"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongod.exe" --datapath=data` works. Similar thing happens for `mongo`.

I want to directly run `mongod` and `mongo` commands, I have seen people directly using it(without going to the directory or specifying the path).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

For a Windows installation, by default you have to use the full path to the exe unless you add it to the PATH.

To add it to the PATH:

`01)`  Get path to bin, something like:  `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin`
`02)`  Press the Windows key, type `env`, select `Edit the system environment variables`
`03)`  On the `Advanced` tab, click `Environment Variables`
`04)`  In the `User variables for xxxx` section, select `path` and then click the `Edit...` button
`05)`  Click `New` and paste your path with a trailing slash, eg:
`C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\`
`06)`  Click `OK`, `OK`, `OK` and restart your command window.
[Source](https://dangphongvanthanh.wordpress.com/2017/06/12/add-mongos-bin-folder-to-the-path-environment-variable/)

The examples you have seen are probably based on UNIX installations which I think by default install mongo as a service (which Windows doesn't) and that is what is called in those examples.

To simplify startup and configuration on Windows, you can also install it as a service. See the Mongo documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#configure-a-windows-service-for-mongodb-community-edition) and the 
"Configure Windows Service for MongoDB' section".

This will then allow you to start and stop Mongo by simply calling

```
net start MongoDB
```

Or

```
net stop MongoDB
```

Answer (score 8):

If installed **MongoDB version** is **6.0** or above, mongo command will not work on Powershell/cmd. If you run the command you will get the following error:

*'mongo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.*

To run mongo commands, you have to install **MongoDB Shell** [from](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/shell)

After installing the shell, extract the zip file, you can rename the extracted folder (mongosh-1.6.0-win32-x64) as "MongoDB Shell" and move that folder to **Windows(:C) > Program Files**

Now open the folder, go to bin and copy the path:

> C:\Program Files\MongoDB Shell\mongosh-1.6.0-win32-x64\bin (or
> C:\Program Files\mongosh-1.6.0-win32-x64\mongosh-1.6.0-win32-x64\bin)

Go to

> Settings > System > About > Advanced system settings > Environment
> Variables > Under System Variables, click on 'Path' then 'Edit' >
> Click 'New' and paste the above copied path > Click 'Ok' 'Ok' 'Ok'

Now open Powershell/cmd, run the command **'mongosh'**

You're all set to work with MongoDB

Comment: Only solution that worked for me in 2023

Answer (score 2):

To add it to the PATH:

**Add Mongo’s bin folder to the Path Environment Variable**
Kindly check the link:
[here](https://dangphongvanthanh.wordpress.com/2017/06/12/add-mongos-bin-folder-to-the-path-environment-variable/%22)
After adding bin folder to the path Environment Variable
then simply type **mongo** in terminal it will start working

Answer (score 1):

Based on welshGaz answer above, I edited the User Path variable but it did not work for me yet. I wasn't able to access the System Path variables.

What I noticed from the errors on the command prompt is that it what missing the "C:\data\db" directory to store its files (I don't know what those files are for just yet). So I created that directory myself and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. I installed through the .msi file provided for windows X64bit. In the installer instructions from MongoDB (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/), I read that you can add `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin` to the System Path. Then it asks to omit the full path to the the MongoDB binaries. That is where I think some information is missing. How are we supposed to omit the full path to the MongoDB binaries?

Currently I can get MongoDB to run mongod using:

`"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\mongod.exe" --dbpath="c:\data\db"`

For `--dbpath="c:\data\db"` you can replace `"c:\data\db"` with the path to your database.

I can also run mongo using:

`"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\mongo.exe"`

Answer (score 1):

reference : [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/install-mongodb)

set your path like this

```
;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin
```

this is worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

use `mongosh` command from your terminal. `mongo` command no longer works for 6.0 and above.

if you are trying to connect from connection url eg `mongodb://localhost:27017/yourdb` try changing it to something like `mongodb://127.0.0.1/yourdb`

Answer (score 0):

Another reason to it if you enabled any property in YAML file and it is not formatted properly. YAML looks for specific syntax like colon":"+space" ".

E.g.-

```
security:
    authorization: enabled
```

Answer (score 0):

In newer Version of MongoDB, the `mongo` command is replaced with `mongosh` to connect with the shell.

So first go to MomgoDB website and download the Mongo Shell zip folder.

Then unzip the folder.The folder would be having these files inside it:

[image: list of files container in the zip]

Then go to the bin folder in it

[image: files inside th bin folder of mongosh]

Now

1. copy the mongosh applicaton
2. Go to the mongo folder in Program files
3. Go inside the server -> version -> bin
4. Paste the mongosh application you copied earlier. This is what your bin folder of MongoDB should look like after pasting `mongosh` application
   [image: file listing]
5. Copy the bin path
6. go to `C` drive : make a folder named `data`, and inside it make another folder named `db`
7. then : edit env variable -> env variable -> system variable -> path -> edit -> add/new path -> paste the bin pat you copied earlier
8. ok -> ok -> ok
9. open cmd and type mongosh ( connected to shell )